# decrementing x does not decrement it's value it just stays there until stack smashing get detected --- C

Tags: c

I have this code

```
int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,14};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int array[n];
    int x=n;

    while(x>0){
        arr[x]=0;
        x--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically I am getting error

```
** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

when debugging in gdb I found when `x` reaches value 2 in `while` loop then it does not decrease and value stays at 2 means there is no outcome of statement `x--;` in the while loop. why is this but when I do code while loop like this

```
 while(x-->0){
        arr[x]=0;
 }
```

error goes away. What's happening there and why is not happening anymore

```
int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,14};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int array[n];
    int x=n;
    while(x>0){
        arr[x]=0;
        x--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr[x]` is UB on the first iteration. Decrement first, then assign

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes this fixed the problem . thanks what is UB?

Comment: @user786 [UB = undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/6699433)

Comment: UB is "undefined behaviour". The C standard does not define how a program with such statements or expressions behaves. Anything can happen, including [_demons flying out of your nose_](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You exceed the bounds of `arr`. If `n` is 3, `arr` has three entries, but you access `arr[3]`. Since `arr[0]` is the first entry, `arr[3]` is the fourth entry. An array with three entries has no fourth entry.

Comment: `An array with three entries has no fourth entry.` can u also please relate this to why x is not decrementing because of `...has no fourth entry`

Comment: @user786 The code has a bug. You have to fix the bug. It really is that simple. Your code will behave in strange and unpredictable ways if you smash the stack -- it will not, in general, be possible to understand them without a *lot* more details. (What platform? What compiler? What compiler options? Etcetera.)

Comment: @user786. As an arbitrary example, you declare `array`, then `x`, so it's conceivable that the compiler places them on the stack in that order. Writing past the end of `array` will then overwrite `x`. I'm not saying that's what's happening in this case: it's just to give you an idea of the sort of thing that could be happening.

Comment: make sense now could be

Comment: make sense now could be in case if I was writing to `array[n]` array